# Server synchronising

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have two domains, one is a .com and the other is a .net
The .com site is running on a dedicated server
The .net site is running on a virtual server

How can I automatically redirect the .com site to the .net site if the .com site fails?

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of ways to skin this cat.

You could use dynDNS.

You could forget about the dedicated server and have a mirrored cloud server with dynamic/elastic IP service and let your cloud provider sort it out.

You could setup load balancing and add some code/setup to your load balancer so it knows not to send visitors to a downed site.

You, or your software, could monitor the .com (and .net), and then switchover using some kind of DNS record editing.

...

Here's a good thread,
serverfault.com/questions/225801 : [1](https://serverfault.com/questions/225801/improving-my-dns-flexibility)